# combining javascript variables into an array

Tags: javascript

I know This is a simple question, but I'm new and I can't figure it out.  I am trying to combine two variables into one array.  I want to combine var word1 and var word2 to make var new.  What is the proper way to do this?

```
var word1 = 'hello'
var word2 = 'good'

var newArray = ['hello','good']
```

Comment: Tried replacing the strings with the vars? [word1, word2]. Btw watch out with new keyword it is reserved. And is the probably what has been confusing you.

Comment: Or another approach: initialize the variables first into the "new" array variable.

Comment: Maybe you where looking to var words = new Array(word1, word2)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize I couldn't use new, but I was using different names in my script anyways. I just typed new in the question to make it simpler.  Thanks for the help everyone, I knew it was simple, I am just starting out learning to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), do:

```
var word1 = 'hello';
var word2 = 'good';
var arr = [];
arr.push(word1, word2);
console.log(arr); //["hello", "good"]
```